# how to update if exists or insert

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a row, or insert it if it doesn't exist. But the `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` won't work since I'm not using a unique column.

```sql
INSERT INTO table (id, user, date, points) VALUES
 (1, 1, '2017-03-03',  25)
 (2, 1, '2017-03-04',  25)
 (3, 2, '2017-03-03', 100)
 (4, 2, '2017-03-04', 150)
```

Each user will have a row for each day they get points.

Is there a way to update if exists or insert, using a single call to MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You seem to know the answer `insert on duplicate key update`.  You just need the right unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_table_user_date ON table(user, date);
```

Then you can do:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, user, date, points)
    VALUES (1, 1, '2017-03-03', 25),
           (2, 1, '2017-03-04', 25),
           (3, 2, '2017-03-03', 100),
           (4, 2, '2017-03-04', 150)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE points = VALUES(points) + points;
```

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` works with any and all unique indexes.  The syntax `VALUES(points)` gets the new value for the column.

Comment: for some reason i was getting a syntax error with the word SET. removed it and it works like a charm.

Comment: @greg . . . My fingers just write that `SET` after the `UPDATE`.  I'm not sure what gets into them.