# Microsoft SQL Server - best way to 'Update if exists, or Insert'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been searching around for the answers to this question, and there's some conflicting or ambiguous information out there, finding it hard to find a for-sure answer.

My context: I'm in node.js using the 'mssql' npm package. My SQL server is Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

I have a record that may or may not exist in a table already -- if it exists I want to update it, otherwise I want to insert it. I'm not sure what the optimal SQL is, or if there's some kind of 'transaction' I should be running in mssql. I've found some options that seem good, but I'm not sure about any of them:

**Option 1:**
[how to update if exists or insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42604132/how-to-update-if-exists-or-insert)

Problem with this is I'm not even sure this is valid syntax in MSSQL. I do like it though, and it seems to support doing multiple rows at once too which I like.

```
INSERT INTO table (id, user, date, points)
    VALUES (1, 1, '2017-03-03', 25),
           (2, 1, '2017-03-04', 25),
           (3, 2, '2017-03-03', 100),
           (4, 2, '2017-03-04', 150)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE points = VALUES(points)
```

---

**Option 2:**

don't know if there's any problem with this one, just not sure if it's optimal. Doesn't seem to support multiple simultaneous rows

```
update test set name='john' where id=3012
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
   insert into test(name) values('john');
```

---

**Option 3:** Merge, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89696/how-to-insert-or-update-using-single-query

Some people say this is a bit buggy or something? This also apparently supports multiple at once which I like.

```
MERGE dbo.Test WITH (SERIALIZABLE) AS T
USING (VALUES (3012, 'john')) AS U (id, name)
    ON U.id = T.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET T.name = U.name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, name) 
    VALUES (U.id, U.name);
```

Comment: `MERGE` has "features" in older versions of SQL Server. There are still some "features", but some have been fixed. With a simple statement like this, you should be fine. I'm, however, surprised you didn't also go for a simple `UPSERT` process: Run an `UPDATE` using the data, and then an `INSERT` with a `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: Read this: https://michaeljswart.com/2017/07/sql-server-upsert-patterns-and-antipatterns/ and this: https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern plus the comments on both

Comment: Option 2 throws error. if is not valid. How to handle this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every one of them has different purpose, pros and cons.

Option 1 is good for multi row inserts/updates. However It only checks primary key constraints.

Option 2 is good for small sets of data. Single record insertion/update. It is more like script.

Option 3 is best for big queries. Lets say, reading from one table and inserting/updating to another accordingly. You can define which condition to be satisfied for insertion and/or update. You are not limited to primary key/unique constraint.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I liked Option 1 the most, however I've confirmed that this syntax doesn't work on my SQL server, so I'm leaning towards option 3

Comment: I'm fine with being limited to primary key constraints though, that's what I'll be going with anyway. Wish there was an option 1 version for MSSQL

Answer (score 13):

If your system is highly concurrent, and performance is important - you can try following pattern, if updates are more common than inserts:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
 
UPDATE dbo.t WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE) SET val = @val WHERE [key] = @key;
 
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
  INSERT dbo.t([key], val) VALUES(@key, @val);
END
 
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Reference: https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern

Also read: https://michaeljswart.com/2017/07/sql-server-upsert-patterns-and-antipatterns/

If inserts are more common:

```
BEGIN TRY     
  INSERT INTO dbo.AccountDetails (Email, Etc) VALUES (@Email, @Etc);       
END TRY     
BEGIN CATCH     
  -- ignore duplicate key errors, throw the rest.
  IF ERROR_NUMBER() IN (2601, 2627) 
    UPDATE dbo.AccountDetails
       SET Etc = @Etc
     WHERE Email = @Email;     
END CATCH
```

I wouldn't use merge, while most of the bugs are apparently fixed - we have had major issues with it before in production.

EDIT ---

Yes above answers were for single rows - For multiple rows, you'd do something like this: The idea behind the locking is the same though

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
 
  UPDATE t WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE) 
    SET val = tvp.val
  FROM dbo.t AS t
  INNER JOIN @tvp AS tvp
    ON t.[key] = tvp.[key];
 
  INSERT dbo.t([key], val)
    SELECT [key], val FROM @tvp AS tvp
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.t WHERE [key] = tvp.[key]);
 
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: This does, however, only handle single rows. With lots of rows that means lots of `INSERT`/`UPDATE` statements which is actually going to be worse for a table that needs high availability, as multiple short locks will take longer than a single lock which will lock for longer than 1 single short lock (to update a single row).

Comment: The second example, in fact, would even produce incorrect results. Imagine if you were inserting 50 rows, and 49 of them were new, and 1 an existing row. The one duplicate would fail, and then the `UPDATE` would be run, updating the single row. Meaning the other 49 rows are lost.

Comment: @Larnu - Yes they were for single row example to show the idea. Added edit for multiple row version. Idea behind the locking is the same though. In highly concurrent scenarios your example, without the hints, could give deadlocks, key violation errors etc. Probably not a concern for most people, but in larger distributed systems it makes a big impact in terms of overall performance

Comment: @Larnu . . . The OP's question only has single row inserts.

Comment: The examples, yes, @GordonLinoff, however, they mention multiple times that they like specific solutions *because* they do support multiple rows, and that they don't like option 2 because it **doesn't**. Recommend ing a solution similar to one the OP has already said they dislike (due to it only supporting one row) doesn't really meet to OP's question for alternatives and clarification.

Comment: Yeah he mentioned it wasn't highly concurrent, so answer probably isn't as relevant to OP - but thought I'd post this just in case someone else in future sees and the discussion around locking is more useful for them in a larger distributed solution. I quite often find the supplemental answers like this with further links on SO are super useful

Answer (score 1):

Extending my comment here. There are known problems with `MERGE` in SQL Server, however, for what you're doing here you will likely be ok. Aaron Bertrand has an article on the subject which you can find here: [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

An alternative, however, for what you could do here would be using an "UPSERT"; `UPDATE` the existing rows, and then `INSERT` the ones that don't exist. This involves 2 separate statements, however, was the method used prior to `MERGE`:

```sql
UPDATE T
SET T.Name = U.Name
FROM dbo.Test T
     JOIN (VALUES (3012, 'john')) AS U (id, name) ON T.id = U.id;

INSERT INTO dbo.Test (Name) --I'm assuming ID is an `IDENTITY` here
SELECT U.name
FROM (VALUES (3012, 'john')) AS U (id, name)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.Test T
                  WHERE T.ID = U.ID);
```

*Note I have not declared any locking or transactions in this example, but you should in any implemented solution.*

Comment: Thanks. I looked at your Caution link, and I don't think my use case will have those problems. These tables i'm inserting /updating into will NOT be 'concurrently used' while I'm doing the updates -- they'll just be dormant apart from my updates. If that's the case, I feel like I should just be going with the Merge..

Comment: Fortunately, you're not using SQL Server 2008, @TKoL , where `MERGE` should simply be avoided.