# Update SQL query for IF EXISTS in SQL db from JSON feed

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, json, sql-server

Currently running the following application, however I require some assistance as I'm fairly new to SQL. What I'm looking to achieve here is to have my records look at the @Pid value and if this value already exists then to update it, otherwise to insert it.
I've currently got the insert method outlined with some help already from the community here, but I could use a pointer on how to update this SQL script.

```
 private static async void UpdateStreetWebApiProperties()
   {
      
       var client = new HttpClient();
       var request = new HttpRequestMessage
       {
           Method = HttpMethod.Get,
           RequestUri = new Uri("https://inventorymanchester.co.uk/api/property-feed/sales/search"),
           Headers =
{
    { "ContentType", "application/json" },
    { "Authorization", "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiNzU5YTJlZjZmYjY0MWE3NjRiZGE5ZjdmYzk2ZDNkMjAwN2IwNTk1MTMyZWJlYjhjMmQ0MTUyZDZlODcwZGI4ODRiOTFmMWEzMGE5NDA0ZWEiLCJpYXQiOjE2NTU3MzQzNjAuNDA5OTY1LCJuYmYiOjE2NTU3MzQzNjAuNDA5OTcxLCJleHAiOjE5NzEzNTM1NjAuMTE2MzYzLCJzdWIiOiIxMzM0MjIiLCJzY29wZXMiOlsicHVibGljLWFwaSJdfQ.kxo8GVwKFRUgfyhrRqUrh6bQvJvv5PfJgken90RulA_hTKuX4zWPs6fZ6RkljSK1ECsPYfeNKF5Z_E-xYekRWtDKOcWCXp-wKKNfHWA7rwVU1NzzeghszqcQ0ojLqcqiJ_sxFXCyouvP6LW1-jlcWmYUaHrBu2rajSSyo-K3RN_uFq85Fc5_XkCAvTzO4U59ZcNU4nhRvj3SG2b4l0kZPGlTePkJafciToZ-Q618DYDtO1Q63hUY6X6CunjIIKXiw8h1o9qG9vlmV60JBuVZ4COzc05H-e4UrA3tYkxa6O6xi3baczCZFr97bTIwXMRlifUh8E6WS29T_2uIjSl5OIcaXLuDhrxYOUrfTsFuGU2SuwKKflps0jAUir1s_T_Fi4sPiC5BqvvbrPSBHXlNQpguIN6nYCK4FXW2ixALjs5e2JKN5gMmOCFeqzEmZJAkrHR0iN7n-UbWwsX7dh8ODss3XprckzadC-f_EHiY4ZDSdKPPnJTukkA0V-ezafoO-hBPeiiPOo-IH3kqCyElUMv2sosV4yaFT8DhFlrivCAktwXz4vkKTUYhjuueWU-QxX1y2MwE0zT32SKb21Bwp4Z7nJ0Fa84_CglbWWZZVglJh6Rrgmmg17DgxpSJx3qCiqqum3UrKGTYuLTube47zjumFQeyy1cYUWmqcRG84OQ" },
},
       };

    using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
       {
           
           response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
           
           
           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
               var properties = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();  
               string strBufJSON = properties;
               string strBufJSON2 = properties;
               
               // above is web service results
          

               JsonModel.JSONModel.Rootobject jData;
         
          
               
               jData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel.JSONModel.Rootobject>(strBufJSON);
     
          
             foreach (var data in jData.data)
               {
                  
                   string strSQL
                 = @"INSERT into [Tortoise_Street_Properties]
                (Pid, bedrooms, postcode, salestatus) VALUES(@Pid, @bedrooms, @postcode, @salestatus)";


                   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=tortoise-final.c4u53gizwfmz.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com,1433;Initial Catalog=TortoiseDB;User Id=tortoise_admin;Password=Casper34;"))
                   {
                       using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
                       {
                       
                           cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Pid", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = data.id;
                           cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@bedrooms", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = data.attributes.bedrooms;
                           cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@postcode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = data.attributes.postcode;
                           cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@salestatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = data.attributes.sale_status;


                           conn.Open();
                           cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
                       }
                   }
               
               
               }
             
           }
           else
           {

               Console.WriteLine("Could not get branch properties");
           }


       }
```

My SQL table exsits as follows:

```
USE [TortoiseDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Tortoise_Street_Properties]    Script Date: 28-Jul-22 
5:09:00 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tortoise_Street_Properties](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Pid] [varchar](255) NULL,
[inlineaddress] [varchar](255) NULL,
[postcode] [varchar](20) NULL,
[description] [varchar](255) NULL,
[bedrooms] [varchar](255) NULL,
[price] [varchar](255) NULL,
[salestatus] [varchar](255) NULL,
[brochure] [varchar](255) NULL,
[longitude] [int] NULL,
[latitude] [int] NULL,
[virtualtour] [varchar](255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I appreciate all your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft SQL Server - best way to 'Update if exists, or Insert'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64061101/microsoft-sql-server-best-way-to-update-if-exists-or-insert)

Comment: See also https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern. And consider using a Table Valued Parameter to do a bulk insert

Comment: Also, you had previous tagged this as asp.net (is this a web application, or ONLY just some code to parse out the web service call - and not a asp.net web applcation). I only note this, since I filter and answer questions that are tagged as asp.net - only a fluke that I saw this question - it was at one time tagged with asp.net. However, if this is not a web based applcation you are writing, then you have correctly removed the asp.net tag.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since the pid might exist (then update), and might not?

Then I suggest you use a data table (they are like recordsets in VBA).

This will thus make the code a WHOLE lot messy.

So, try somthing like this:

```
        foreach (var data in jData.data)
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Tortoise_Street_Properties] WHERE Pid = @Pid";
            DataTable rstData = new DataTable();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=tortoise-final.c4u53gizwfmz.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com,1433;Initial Catalog=TortoiseDB;User Id=tortoise_admin;Password=Casper34;"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Pid", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = data.id;
                    rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                    DataRow MyOneRow;

                    if (rstData.Rows.Count == 0)
                    {
                        // data does not exist, add it
                        MyOneRow = rstData.NewRow();
                        MyOneRow["Pid"] = data.id;
                        rstData.Rows.Add(MyOneRow);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MyOneRow = rstData.Rows[0];
                    }

                    // update the data
                    MyOneRow["bedrooms"] = data.attributes.bedrooms;
                    MyOneRow["postcode"] = data.attributes.postcode;
                    MyOneRow["salestatus"] = data.attributes.sale_status;

                    // do whatever more you want above, and then save data
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
                    SqlCommandBuilder daU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                    da.Update(rstData);
                }
            }
        }
```

The nice deal with above is we don't have to mess with parmters, get strong typed values, and the same code for the update vs the insert works.

I would also consider that you build a function for "each" section of the code you want to process.

eg somthing like this:

```
        foreach (jdat.Datum data in jData.data)
        {

            // update property
            MyProperyUpdate(data);
            // more update code - whatever
        }

    }


    void MyProperyUpdate(jdat.Datum data)
    {
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Tortoise_Street_Properties] WHERE Pid = @Pid";
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=tortoise-final.c4u53gizwfmz.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com,1433;Initial Catalog=TortoiseDB;User Id=tortoise_admin;Password=Casper34;"))
        {
            // etc. etc.
```

Since you going to have quite a few parts to pull out, then you want to code each little part as a little routine - not have one monster routine to crack open and peel apart that large complex data structure.

Not a huge deal. But, often, using a datatable works better, and also results in your have to write MUCH less messy SQL for updates.