# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON' - SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone tell me why the following syntax is resulting in error? I would like to update the ip address field with dynamic ip addresses if a current record exists with a matching primary key.

```
INSERT INTO Overview ([Computername], [IpAddress]) 
VALUES('test', '127.0.0.1') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY 
       UPDATE Overview SET IpAddress = '127.0.0.1';
```

Comment: `SQL Server` does not support `ON DUPLICATE KEY`. use [merge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "ON DUPLICATE KEY" allowed in MS SQL Server. This syntax is only allowed on MySQL.

Comment: Would you be able to suggest a clean alternative?

Comment: You can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64061101/microsoft-sql-server-best-way-to-update-if-exists-or-insert for few solutions.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Will shoot you the upvote here in a second.